# Excel2010 - How to do graph of the same year's period from multiple years data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I want to ask you if it's possible to make a graph that can show comparation of data collected through 3 years.

Year 1:

```
DATE        2014
5.6.2014     500
8.7.2014     600
15.8.2014    700
4.9.2014     800
22.10.2014   900
```

Year 2:

```
DATE        2015
12.6.2015    400
13.7.2015    500
20.8.2015    600
6.9.2015     700
10.10.2015   800
```

Year 3:

```
DATE        2016
19.6.2016    300
9.7.2016     400
2.8.2016     500
17.9.2016    600
16.10.2016   700
```

I need a graph with **X** axis showing date from june to october (any year), to compare how the data changed through the years.

The data was collected in different dates, so they cannot be shown on the same *"spot"* every month (and the example I used is only showing one per month, I have a real table with multiple data).

Is it even possible?

When using secondary **X** axis, I can do this with two *"years"*. But there is **no** possibility to add 3rd axis.

Thank you!!!

Comment: It looks like you have one value per month for the months that have values, and the day can vary a lot.  Something to think about: you're comparing year to year.  If the process generating the numbers is very month-specific and/or random in the short term (so day is irrelevant), you can treat the months like categories (a bar or column chart with a bar per month).  But if there is any kind of shorter-term pattern or trend going on, that will distort what you see when you aggregate by month.  (cont'd)

Comment: In that case, it would be better to treat time as a continuous variable, and plot values where they actually fall in the calendar (an X-Y or scatter chart).  You can do that by making each year a separate series and make the dates all the same year, stored as actual date values (just format to hide the year and use the series name to identify the year).

Answer (score 1):

Just add a column containing `MONTH()` of your date field, and graph this column as `x` axis.

If you want the data sets automatically labeled, copy them in separate columns, with the column header containing the year.

Answer (score 1):

You can organize your data like this: In the first column, put the dates you need (1.6 - 31.10.). Then, make columns for every year you need (2014, 2015...) and put the data in corresponding cells (see image).

[image]

After this, simply select the data and create the chart (in this case, I chose clustered column).

Is this what you had in mind? If not, please show us your example with the secondary X axis so we know what you are trying to make.